# Generate linq query to get count of distinct records in single column

Tags: sql, linq

I want to generate the linq query analogous to

```
select distinct HashTagName, count(HashTagName) as CountOf 
from tblUserHashTags group by HashTagName order by CountOf desc
```

Please suggest me for the same.

Comment: Please never just dump SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), *and* show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With query syntax it should be pretty straight forward:-

```
var result = from uh in db.tblUserHashTags
             group uh by uh.HashTagName into g
             let count = g.Count()
             orderby count descending
             select new 
             {
                 HashTagName = g.Key,
                 CountOf = count
             };
```

Comment: @Deepak.jagtap - You're Welcome :) You can accept the answer if that helped you. Check this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
(from g in contextObj.tblUserHasgTags 
group g by g.HashTagName into grp
select new {
 tagName = grp.key,
 CountOf = grp.Count()
 }).OrderByDescending(x=>x.CountOf);
```

Comment: You will never get `HashTagName` after `grp.Key`. Also, there is no point calling `Distinct()` as grouping will anyways return single key.

Comment: Hii.. shilpa  var listTrendingHashTags = (from c in db.tblHashTagMasters
                                            where c.IsDeleted != true
                                            orderby c.HashTagName
                                            group c by c.HashTagName
                                                into grp
                                            select new APIGetTrendingHashTagsModel { HashTagId = c.HashTagId, HashTagName = c.HashTagName, TimeStamp = c.TimeStamp }).Distinct(c.HashTagName);

Comment: I tried for same . but the problem is i am getting result in my customised model not returning values directly in model same as table defination.  It doesn't allowing me for the same

Comment: @RahulSingh I agreed with Distinct() part, but as far as I know grp.key.HashTagName will be accessible.

Comment: @ShilpaSoni - No it won't be accessible since you are grouping without anonymous type - `g.HashTagName`. It will be accessible if you group using anonymous type like this:- `new { g.HashTagName }`

Comment: @Deepak.jagtap which query are you trying to run? The one you mentioned in your comment or the one in your question?

Comment: I have done with the solution given by Rahul...Thanks Rahul

Comment: Please mention the question was correct. So that i can get reputations above 15

Comment: @Deepak.jagtap - For accepting the answer you don't need reputation of 15, you can simply do this by clicking the right button on the left. Also, you should not ask for upvoting question.